# deleted files in eclipse, how to get them back

Tags: java, git

In eclipse, I deleted some java files but now I need them back, here is my git log:

> commit efc5c0af442a8419eec19997b84c71ebae1b1be4 Author: jack_Git
>    Date:   Sun Jan 11 10:17:28 2015 -0800
>
> ```
> screwed up
> ```
>
> commit 735349994c3150de90b539031644b8e42c03f277 Author: jack_Git
>    Date:   Sun Jan 11 10:07:03 2015 -0800
>
> ```
> manifest changed
> ```
>
> commit cc4c33778e333ea15577c6794e42fc2856d9bee1 Author: jack_Git
>    Date:   Sun Jan 11 10:02:34 2015 -0800
>
> ```
> merged the asynctask
> ```
>
> commit 781a8f41e1168abd3b6e44d17df0f117b78b7a26 Author: jack_Git
>    Date:   Sun Jan 11 08:55:28 2015 -0800

I want to roll back to the "manifest changed" commit.

Here is what I have tried:

git revert 735349994c3150de90b539031644b8e42c03f277

But now it states that I am in the middle of a merge!

Comment: Try `git checkout 735349`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confused by the meaning of `git revert`. It produces a new commit *that reverts (undoes) a particular commit*. In your case, it would undo the changes *in the 
"manifest changed" commit*. That might be what causes the merge. 
If you want to undo the "screwed up" commit, you should do `git revert efc5c0af44`. Or you could do a `git reset 735349994c31` which is a bit more brute force and less safe as it changes history.

If you just want particular files back, you could also try `git checkout <commit> -- <filename>`

For more on git reverting, see this tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your `HEAD` is clean, before revert.

Second, after revert, some file might include double content from your HEAD & the old commit,
you need first `git status` to see which files have conflict, then open those files, do merge by hand to solve lines like following:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 97d2375... ...
```

---

Instead of use revert, maybe you can `git checkout` the commit, copy out the deleted files, then back to your `HEAD` add those files, and commit.